# on redirection my array updates on the new page and then the view disappears, 1second after the redirection

Tags: angular, nativescript

[image]My array updates because i could see the array for 1 second before the view disappears, plus everything is working totally fine only the view disappears, i have console logged the data and the data reaches everywhere properly, this is the code.. and deleting from the array works perfectly

dairy.service.ts -

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Diary, Page } from "../models/diary.modle";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DiaryService {

  diaries: Array<Diary> = [
      {
            id: "0",
            name: "Personal",
            createdOn: "25 FEB 2020",
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo.",
            pages: [
                {
                    id: "0",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede."
                },
                {
                    id: "1",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo."
                },
                {
                    id: "2",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo."
                },
                {
                    id: "3",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "Personal 1",
            createdOn: "25 FEB 2020",
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo.",
            pages: [
                {
                    id: "0",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede."
                },
                {
                    id: "1",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo."
                },
                {
                    id: "2",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo."
                },
                {
                    id: "3",
                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sagittis, mi consequat venenatis pulvinar, justo."
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

  diariesListener = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Diary>>([]);
  diaryListener = new BehaviorSubject<Diary>({ id: "", name: "", createdOn: "", description: "", pages: []});

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  getDiariesListener() {
    return this.diariesListener.asObservable();
  }

  getDiaryListener() {
    return this.diaryListener.asObservable();
  }

  fetchDiaries() {
    this.diariesListener.next(this.diaries);
  }

  fetchDiary(id: number) {
    this.diaryListener.next(this.diaries[id]);
  }

  addDiary(name: string, description: string) {

    const date = new Date();
    const day = date.getDate();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    let month: string;

    switch (date.getMonth()) {
        case 0: month = "JAN"; break;
        case 1: month = "FEB"; break;
        case 2: month = "MAR"; break;
        case 3: month = "APR"; break;
        case 4: month = "MAY"; break;
        case 5: month = "JUN"; break;
        case 6: month = "JUL"; break;
        case 7: month = "AUG"; break;
        case 8: month = "SEP"; break;
        case 9: month = "OCT"; break;
        case 10: month = "NOV"; break;
        case 11: month = "DEC"; break;
    }

    const diary: Diary =  {
        id: Math.random().toString(),
        name,
        createdOn: day + " " + month + " " + year,
        description,
        pages: []
    };

    this.diaries.push(diary);

    this.diariesListener.next(this.diaries);

    this.router.navigate(["/diaries"]);
  }

}
```

create-diary.ts - ( service injected and method called)

```
constructor(private diaryService: DiaryService) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

createDiary() {

        if (this.form.value.name === null || this.form.value.description === null) {
            return;
        }
        this.diaryService.addDiary(this.form.value.name, this.form.value.description);
    }
```

diaries.component.ts - ( handling new array )

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.diaryService.fetchDiaries();
        this.diariesSub = this.diaryService.getDiariesListener().subscribe((result) => {
            this.diaries = result;
            this.diaries.forEach(() => {
                this.rows.push("auto");
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push same `diaries` array object which might causing issue. simple trick can be by passing diaries array to `next` function using `spread operator`.

```
this.diariesListener.next([...this.diaries]);
```

In this diariesListener which detect change cause of new reference point

Comment: sorry but its not working... only adding something on to the array is having such behavior

Comment: may be I am interpreting your question in incorrect way. can you repro same thing with working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) ?

Comment: actually i think its about nativescript and not angular related, i am running it in an emulator i don't think thats possible on stackblitz.....

Comment: hmm, can you check by creating same usecase outside natvescript and see if problem persist ? may be lighter version of it. may be this way you can come to certain conclusion ? since question is unclear we cannot answer it in right way